# How to view complete commits when tracking history of a single file in Git?

Tags: git, gitk

I have a Git repository with about a two years of history in it. I have single file in it, for which I wish to find all the commits, and for each commit: all the other files that were committed in it. Let's assume this file is named file.txt. I can run gitk with this file as argument:

```
gitk file.txt
```

and I do get each commit. However, browsing that tree in gitk only shows changes done to file.txt. I'd like to see what other files were changed in that commit. I can copy paste each commit SHA1 and display it, but there are over hundred of commits related to this file.

I notice that "comments" section in bottom-right part of screen is empty (only shows text "Comments"). Maybe a list of files could be shown there?

Comment: For EOL else where see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10277/ignore-whitespaces-changes-in-all-git-commands

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the command line,

```
git log -p --full-diff file.txt
```

will output what you want.

If you must see it in gitk, invoke it with *no* arguments, find commit "touching path" file.txt, and the commit contains that file will be bold. And you can use the "up" and "down" buttons to traverse through it.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I need. Thank you very much (I'm sorry I can only upvote and accept it)

Answer (score 11):

You can actually have '--full-diff' functionality in gitk, just not directly from the command line.
Just do the following:

- Start gitk the usual way, e.g.: `gitk file.txt`
- Select 'View -> Edit view...' from the menu. Verify that you are editing the 'Command line' view.
- In the edit box next to "Additional arguments to git log", type `--full-diff`
- Click "Apply" or hit [F5].

That should do it. Why gitk doesn't allow you to use this from the command line is a mystery to me, for it is a very useful option.

Answer (score 4):

Another solution from the mailing list dated far back in [2008](http://marc.info/?l=git&m=122335116419147):

> Try turning off the option "Limit diffs to listed paths" in the 
>   preferences menu (or adding "set limitdiffs 0" to your ~/.gitk).

Comment: this is the only solution working for me.. the ~/.gitk is not working but changing in preferences works fine