# gitk <path> showing other changes in different directories in commits

Tags: git, gitk

I would like to see commits touching specific directory but in the commits must be listed changes outside of the directory.

For example I have:

```
repo/src/moduleA > gitk .
```

So I will see commits touching this moduleA:

commit1
commit13
commit45

If in commit1 there are changes in moduleB I want to see them.

Is it possible in gitk? or in any other tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `gitk` I don't know, but with `git log`:

```
git log --full-diff -p src/moduleA
```

> --full-diff
>              Without this flag, git log -p ...  shows commits that touch the specified paths, and diffs about the same specified paths. With this, the full diff is shown for commits that touch the specified paths; this means that "..." limits only
>              commits, and doesn’t limit diff for those commits.

Comment: this looks good, I tried to use --full-diff in gitk View > Edit View > Additional arguments to git log .. but its not working :-/ for now I will use the git log cmd line thanks

Comment: hm I found duplicate .. its doable in preferences of gitk :) check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20065720/3876138)

Comment: @otopolsky Good job finding the duplicate. I saw that solution for `gitk` but I couldn't make it work. :-( Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) (and possible `gitk`), you can have multiple paths as parameters:

```
cd repo
git log -- src/moduleA src/moduleB
```

However, that would show commits with modification in A *or B or (A and B).

Comment: `gitk` runs `git rev-list` (which shares the code with `git log`) to select commits, so yes, this should work in `gitk` as well.

Comment: @torek that is what I thought indeed, but that still might select too many commits compared to what the OP expects.